# R: Visualise the likelihood in Bayesian binomial regression with group-level effects using brms

Tags: r, logistic-regression, bayesian, brms

I have multiple series of Bernoulli trials in different groups, and fit a binomial model using brms. I would like to visualise the likelihood, like in the image below.

[image: Visualisation of prior, likelihood and posterior]

I know how to plot the posterior draws using `as_draws_df`, but I do not know how to extract the likelihood from the `brms` model (is it even available as such?)

My model definition is as follows: `N_succes | trials(N_trials) ~ treatment + (1 | study)` using `family = binomial()`.

If I had only one study, I would visualise the likelihood using `curve(dbeta(x, N_succes, N_trials - N_success)`. I imagine that with multiple studies I could just sum the number of success and the number of trials over all studies, but then I would ignore the grouping factor I specify in the model. This seems incorrect.

Is the posterior of a brm-model with an uninformative prior the same as the likelihood?

Can you help me extract the likelihood from the `brm` object, or define it myself?